# Partial validations in multistep forms (Wizard)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a multistep form, which I created with wizard. Basically the first tep of the form is user/sign_up - which in my understanding not a step yet. After hitting the sign-up button, user moves to the "real" first step, which is `:address.`

```
    class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps :address


    def show
      @user = current_user || User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      render_wizard
    end


    def update
      @user = current_user || User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      @user.update!(user_params)
      render_wizard @user
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :street, :house_number, :city, :zip_code)
    end

    def redirect_to_finish_wizard(options = nil, params = nil)
        redirect_to new_user_profile_path(current_user)
    end

end
```

This is basically the end of the form already. All gets saved to the user. Now I am stuck with validations.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[facebook]

    has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
    after_create :create_profile
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :street, presence: true
    validates :house_number, presence: true
    validates :city, presence: true
    validates :zip_code, presence: true

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
            name = auth.info.name
            user.first_name = name.split(" ")[0]
            user.last_name = name.split(" ")[1]

        end
    end
end
```

I would love to work with the the conditional validations in my model and only validate presence if on a certain step. This should be easy, as I theoretically only have one step, which is address. All I find on the internet, is way too complicated. Question is, do I have to somehow change user/sign_up to a first step in the form and address would be the second step? Or is it fine like this? And if so, can I just add the "if" statements to the address attributes in my validations, somehow defining what is the address step? Would it work like this?

```
def on_address_step?
wizard.steps = wizard.steps.first
end
```

Or how do I define it? The validations would look like this then:

```
validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :street, presence: true, if: :on_address_step?
    validates :house_number, presence: true, if: :on_address_step?
    validates :city, presence: true, if: :on_address_step?
    validates :zip_code, presence: true, if: :on_address_step?
```

This is surely not that easy. For now this also doesn't work. How do I need to change it? Thanks. 
P.S: here is also my Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to user_steps_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :street, :house_number, :city, :zip_code)
  end

end
```

Comment: Please make clear what the output you are trying to get. Is this like user sign up with the credentials and then the form sends for the step two. I think you can do this with out using `Wicked::Wizard`.

Comment: I am using the gem already. I have my validations, but in first step I only want to validate name, surname. In second step I wish to validate all data relevant to the adddres - speaking the fields should be filled out. Now it validated address and name all in first step.

Comment: Update your validations rule with `validates :street, presence: true, on: :on_address_step?`. Change `if:` with `on:`.

Comment: I need to define :on_address_step? differently. For now this method doesn't work.

Comment: Is this the method provides by the Gem.

Comment: No. This was basically the question.

Comment: Then you need to define the method!

Comment: I know this. But I don't know how. Maybe I didn't make it clear in my describtion, but basically I need to somehow specify when to validate name and when address. But I couldn't find this out by myseld. This is why I was asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

If filling in the address is a completely separate process I would just branch the address out into its own model and controller.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_one :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  belongs_to :user
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :street, 
            :house_number, :city, :zip_code, presence: true
end
```

This avoids turning your user model into even more of a god object and removes the need for the conditional validation that makes your model much more aware of the UX steps than it should be.

```
# routes.rb
resources :addresses, only: [:new, :create]

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to new_address_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end

class AddressesController < ApplicationController
  # You should have some sort of method that checks if the user
  # is signed in and redirect otherwise
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /addresses/new
  def new
    # I'm assuming you have some sort of method to fetch the signed in user
    @address = current_user.build_address
  end

  # POST /addresses
  def create
    @address = current_user.build_address(address_params)
    if @address.save
      redirect_to '/somepath'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def address_params
    params.require(:address).permit(
      :first_name, :last_name, :street, 
      :house_number, :city, :zip_code
    )
  end
end
```

---

```
<%= form_with(model: @address) %>
  # ... inputs
<% end %>
```

I doubt you really want the complexity involved with using Wicked which is ok if you really need a long multiple step form but in this case there is a far simpler and better design choice.

Comment: I see your point. But for me it's important to learn more about these forms. So, I am really hoping I can manage this issue and still have my multistep form.

Comment: The actual issue was, that the sign-up was a registrion controller action (create), while filling out the address and saving, was the usersteps controller action (update). The answer for this particulyr problem is really easy and I posted it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59839813/rails-partial-validations-depending-on-conrtoller). Maybe you are interested. And thanks again for help!